# How to inherit MutableList in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to inherit MutableList, and add my own function to it. For example:

```
class CompositeJob : MutableList<Job> {
    fun cancelAllJobs() {
        for (job in this) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

> Class 'CompositeJob' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member
>   public abstract val size: Int defined in kotlin.collections.MutableList

How can I inherit MutableList, so I can use its original methods like add() and isEmpty(), and add my own one?

Thanks.

Comment: Point your mouse in `CompositeJob` class name and do `Alt + Enter` now those methods are partially implemented for you. BTW implementing `MutableList` is kinda hassle IMO, will you consider extending to `ArrayList<Job>` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) is an interface - it doesn't implement any of its methods, just declares them. If you want to implement `MutableList` from scratch, you'll have to implement all 20 of its methods plus the `size` property, as your error already told you.

You can, however, subclass actual implementations of this interface, for example [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

```
class CompositeJob : ArrayList<Job>() {
    fun cancelAllJobs() {
        for (job in this) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: If you're just looking to group coroutine `Job` instances, you should use a parent [`Job`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/), a [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html), and [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) at this point, instead of collecting jobs like this manually.

Comment: How do I create an empty instance of CompositeJob?

Comment: You can create an instance by calling its constructor: `val composite = CompositeJob()`

Comment: As simple as that ey. Cheers

Comment: in KMM `ArrayList` This type is final, so it cannot be inherited from

Answer (score 17):

One option other answers don't mention is [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html):

```
class CompositeJob : MutableList<Job> by mutableListOf() {
    fun cancelAllJobs() {
        for (job in this) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

is basically equivalent to

```
class CompositeJob : MutableList<Job> {
    private val impl: MutableList<Job> = mutableListOf()
    override fun size() = impl.size()
    override fun add(x: Job) { impl.add(x) }
    // etc for all other MutableList methods

    fun cancelAllJobs() {
        for (job in this) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of all the members is not the only way to achieve what you need.  
An easier way is  create an extension function like this:

```
fun MutableList<Job>.cancelAllJobs() {
    this.forEach { it.cancel() }
}
```

Now you can call `myList.cancelAllJobs()` for every `MutableList<Job>` object.

Answer (score 0):

As I have tested you need to make `CompositeJob` an `abstract` as error also suggest. After that, you can able to override `add()` and `isEmpty()` from `MutableList`

So your code looks like as below:

```
abstract class CompositeJob : MutableList<Job> {
override fun add(element:Job): Boolean
  {

  }

override fun isEmpty(): Boolean 
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid inheritance, or if the concrete class methods are marked `final`, then you can use composition and redirect all method calls which are not overridden. Here's a template:

```
class MyMutableList<T> : MutableList<T> {
    private val list = mutableListOf<T>()
    override val size get() = list.size

    // MutableList<T>
    override fun add(element: T): Boolean = list.add(element)
    override fun add(index: Int, element: T) = list.add(index, element)
    override fun addAll(elements: Collection<T>): Boolean = list.addAll(elements)
    override fun addAll(index: Int, elements: Collection<T>): Boolean = list.addAll(index, elements)
    override fun clear() = list.clear()
    override fun remove(element: T): Boolean = list.remove(element)
    override fun removeAll(elements: Collection<T>): Boolean = list.removeAll(elements)
    override fun removeAt(index: Int): T = list.removeAt(index)
    override fun retainAll(elements: Collection<T>): Boolean = list.retainAll(elements)
    override fun set(index: Int, element: T): T = list.set(index, element)

    // List<T>
    override fun contains(element: T): Boolean = list.contains(element)
    override fun containsAll(elements: Collection<T>): Boolean = list.containsAll(elements)
    override fun get(index: Int): T = list.get(index)
    override fun indexOf(element: T): Int = list.indexOf(element)
    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean = list.isEmpty()
    override fun iterator(): MutableIterator<T> = list.iterator()
    override fun lastIndexOf(element: T): Int = list.lastIndexOf(element)
    override fun listIterator(): MutableListIterator<T> = list.listIterator()
    override fun listIterator(index: Int): MutableListIterator<T> = list.listIterator(index)
    override fun subList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int): MutableList<T> =
        list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)
}
```

...of course, this might add an additional layer of indirection, possibly affecting list performance with a slight overhead.